# Relationship between magnitudes of partial derivatives when one is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f(x, y)$ be a real vector-valued function. Then, if we know that:

- the range of $x$ is bounded (say to $[0,1]$),
- the magnitude of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is bounded in $L_2$-norm such that $\Vert \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Vert_2 \leq K$, i.e. the function is $K$-Lipschitz in $y$.

What does this imply about the magnitude of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, i.e. about $\Vert \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Vert_2$ ?

Note that we have no indication about the function being Lipschitz in general, but just in one variable. We only know that $x$ assumes a bounded range.